# Does memory allocation and initialisation take place separatelty during compile time and runtime?

Tags: memory, memory-management, runtime, dynamic-memory-allocation, compile-time

When we declare a variable, say an int, I would like to know the steps involved during the memory allocation and initialisation. and also for a pointer

```
int x = 5;
```

now during compile time, 4-bytes is allocated to the integer x. but when does the memory gets filled with the value 5? does the initialisation take place during compilation or runtime execution.
similarly, consider

```
int x = 5;
int* p = &x;
```

in these 2 lines what is process of allocation and initialisation.

Answer (score 2):

Variables initialization depends on the kind of variables. Global or static variables are initialised at compile time, while automatic variables are entirely managed at run time.

**Global variables**

- At compile time, the value of all global variables is known. These values are written by the compiler to specific sections of an object file.
- At link time, all the object files are gathered and memory locations are determined for each variable. This allows to know the address of every variable, in case one of these addresses is assigned to another variable.
  As a result, an executable file is generated that contains a description of the content of every section ( text, data, rodata, etc). In the data or rodata section, are written the values of all initialized global variables.
- at run time, the loader reads the description of the different sections and asks to the OS memory. It then will copy the content of all sections to their respective memory locations.
  This is the way variable are initialised with a value determined at compile or link time.
  The only exception is for variables that are initialized at zero (or not initialized). They are located in a special section (frequently named bss). To reduce the size of executable files, these zero values are not written in the executable. Instead, before executing `main()`, a runtime procedure will memset to zero all the content of the bss section.

**Automatic variables**

The procedure is completely different. One does not know the location of these variable before the program runs and the only way is to compute their values by machine instructions.

So the compiler first determines if theses vars will be located in register or memory, and when entering the function, the first instructions will be to reserve stack space for local variables and to initialize their values. This is done by means of regular machine instructions.

In case the value is the address of another variable (say y=&x),
* if x is a local (automatic) variable, the address will be computed by writing to `y` the sum of the content of the stack pointer register and a given offset determined by the compiler
* if x is a global or static variable, at link time, once the addresses of global variables are known, the linker modifies the instructions generated by the compiler to write the proper address in the register or stack location used to represent `y`.

Answer (score 0):

There are situations where there is no way around defining at runtime:
if user_input == "yes":
    my_var = 5
else:
    my_var = 7

But normally it depends on the concept the responsible compiler programmer has implemented. If you use a different compiler or different language then things might be different.